# Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wslconfig.exe /list

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open vs code it spawns a new terminal showing this error message. How can I solve it?

```
 Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wslconfig.exe /list
```

Comment: `wslconfig` sound like it would be part of [the Windows Subystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Maybe one of your plugins depends on that?

Comment: I started getting the same error today. Everytime I open a new VSCode window it opens up the built in terminal and then throws that error. I think it has something to do with the most recent update. Because I never had this occur before - updated VS yesterday before bed and in the morning this started happening.

Comment: I started getting the same error after updating to 1.51.0 VS Code version on Windows machine

Answer (score 4):

Just update VS Code extension [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) to v1.51.3.

Answer (score 0):

open command line and navigate to a folder of your projects then type code . to open vscode. thats how I solved this issue.